# Learning curve plot keeping test data constant

Tags: python, for-loop, machine-learning

First I defined X and y, which are partly depicted below.

```
    from sklearn import svm
    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

    X = array([[11.8, 0., 3.4, 5.7, 0., 5.7],
    [33.4, 6.8, 0., 5.7, 0., 5.7],
    [33.4, 6.8, 0., 5.7, 0., 5.7])

    y = array([ 1.,  1.,  0.])
```

I am plotting a learning curve with the dictionary created in the code below:

```
#First separation of test data
X_train_prev, X_test_prev, y_train_prev, y_test_prev = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)

#storing test and training error in dictionary as a function of decreasing test size
array = np.arange(0.01,0.9,0.025)
dicto = {}


for i in array: 
    X_train, _, y_train, _ = train_test_split(X_train_prev, y_train_prev, test_size = i)
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)    

    #use the previous test data...
    test = clf.score(X_test_prev, y_test_prev) 
    train = clf.score(X_train, y_train)
    dicto[i] = test, train

print(dicto)
```

My learning curve looks like: 
[image: learning curve]

The problem is that the test error is independent on the model. How is this possible? How should I change my code in such a way that the test error is dependent on the trained model?

Comment: could you provide a full working snippet, ideally with a sample-data set provided in sklearn

Comment: I edited my post. Thanks for your comment michael_j_ward

Comment: by working snippet, I mean that I should be able to copy and paste the snippet into python and get the result you are experiencing. I don't immediately the error, so it could be either in your classifier setup or in your plotting function- so I need an entire working snippet to be able to diagnose the issue

Comment: isn't your data heavily unbalanced, with 88% of single class? (thus this result is simply trivial model saying "always true"?)

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris()
X    = data.data
y    = data.target
clf  = SVC()
#====
#Your code
#====
test_training_error = dicto.values()
test_training_error_sorted = sorted(test_training_error, key = lambda e:e[0])   #I think this is important.

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(test_training_error_sorted[0], test_training_error_sorted[1])
```

I used the data from sklearn, the results of this is ok. The figure is normal. Maybe you should check your data of code and sorted data for plotting figure.